# Cloth simulations take too much ram

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I have a very intense scene involving several cloth simulations and rigid body physics. The rigid body physics have been working fine. I'm able to play through them and bake them. The cloth simulations on the other hand make blender crash saying that my computer is out of application memory. My machine has 32gb of ram, so it should not easily run out of application memory. This doesn't do this with any other blender simulation I have tried. Any ideas on how to either reduce the complexity of the simulations or workarounds for getting things to work?

Comment: be sure that you are using blender 64bit version and a 64bit OS, and use some administrative tool to see the memory usage and the memory allocated by blender to know if that is really your hardware limit or just blender

Answer (score 2):

You might have a scene such as this.

Scene:

- (1) A model/mesh of a humanoid with animated walking.
- (2) A cloth plane/mesh that is serving as a cape for the humanoid.

Assumptions:

- (A) Let's assume that (1) is a high-res polygon mesh.
- (B) Let's assume that (2) is a high-res polygon mesh.
- (C) Let's assume that (1) is a collision object for (2).

The amount of collisions for (C) is going to be very high, especially since (A) and (B) is true. There are many possible solutions:

Solutions:

- (I) Reduce the subdivisions for (1), resulting in low-res humanoid.
- (II) Reduce the subdivisions for (2), resulting in low-res cape.
- (III) Create a copy of (1) and reduce the subdivisions for only the
  copy. Disable the original humanoid mesh as a collision object;
  enable the copy of the humanoid (low-res) as a collision object. Now,
  the cape will collide/simulate with the low-res humanoid instead of
  the high-res humanoid. Finally, make sure to bake/cache/save the
  simulation for the cape; now only render the cape & the high-res
  humanoid (don't render the low-res humanoid).

You can do (I), (II), or both (I) & (II). However, I think the better solution is (III) where you make a low-res copy to stand in as a collision object.

Feel free to offer any follow-up questions/comments.